# CakePHP ACL Auth Trouble

Tags: cakephp, acl, authentication

I love CakePHP, but cannot wrap my head around the ACL/Auth subject. Everything else comes together nicely, but when it comes to this, I am lost. On top of it, I cannot finish my application if this is not solved. Therefore, I desperately need your help.

Things to note:

- I have tried a few of the plugins available, but to no avail.
- I have used tutorials online as well as the latest CakePHP book by Mariano, with no success.
- I have tried on my own, also to no avail

Why is it so hard to get this accomplished?

These are my questions:

- Is there any other way to handle Access Rights in a CakePHP application with Multiple Admin, users, etc?
- For the possibility that ACL is the only/best way, how else could I approach this?
- What could I possibly be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say that you have already tried a few of the available plugins, you have maybe already tried my own one: http://www.alaxos.net/blaxos/pages/view/plugin_acl It is mainly a graphical interface that allows to set the ACL permissions when they are used to grant/deny access to actions.

My point here is that in addition to the plugin itself, I made available a very simple sample application http://www.alaxos.net/blaxos/pages/view/demo_plugins that uses this plugin. It may help you if you install it and look at the code, as the application has some public parts, and some parts protected by the ACLComponent.

Comment: Looks like a sweet plugin, I have to implement ACL in my newest Cake project in a short while and I think I'll take a look at it!

Comment: Correct, I have not tried your plugin and if I can make it work like it is in your demo, I would be GOLDEN. I have downloaded and followed the instructions. However, it is throwing an error. I use a configurations_controller.php in app_controller.php beforeFilter's to check whether the Site is On or OFF. I have something like this `if($this->Configuration->get_site_status() == 1){` .... The error I am getting is `Undefined property: AclController::$Configuration`. How can I fix this issue? Is it possible this way?

Comment: You have a controller that is a property of your AppController ? That is not exactly following the standard Cake way of doing things. If you need to call an action of another controller, you should probably use the `$this->requestAction()` function. Or maybe the `get_site_status()` method could be placed in a model. Anyway, the question here is _how do you initialize the `Configuration` property ?_, because it seems that this is not done when you are on the plugin.

Comment: Basically, I create the Configurations Controller and was using `var $uses = array('Configuration')`. However, I have scratched that all out and will create something similar, but as a Component. I have FINALLY AND SUCCESSFULLY installed your plugin and it is working beautifully on most occasions. I am having some problems here and there, but I am sure it is because of my MISCONFIGURATIONS. I will continue attempting to fix them and if I am not successful, I will post back for help. KUDOS TO YOU FOR A GREAT SCRIPT. THANKS SO MUCH! THIS LIFT A HUGE WEIGHT OVER THAT WAS OVER MY HEAD....

Comment: Cool if it can help you, and thanks for your congratulations :-)

Comment: No problem. I have fixed all the little issues that I had with my Articles Controller not allowing me access. Basically I had to access any other controllers that are directly related to the Articles, like Categories, and add the $this->Auth->allow to all public actions as well. PROBLEM FIXED. I am relieved and now I can move on to accomplish other things that needs to be done before my launch date of 01/01/2012. BTW, I am working on totally redesigning my website located at bravanews.com. I currently run phpcow.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the pains in Cake, the complexity of ACL..

Is there any other way? Well, yes. Yes, in the sense that you can cook up your own access rights management, and simply go around the cake's ACL implementation. For example, you could have a role based ACL where roles would be pretty much a fixed list. This can be accomplished in many ways, one of which was demonstrated with [DarkAuth](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/theChrisWalker/2008/06/11/darkauth-v1-3-an-auth-component).

Further more, don't try to fit your app into the cake's ACL scheme if it doesn't suit you. Bake your own, cake offers you the option of plugging in your own objects for auth/ACL stuff, so use it!

But do note that any feature-rich ACL system you want to create yourself might end up looking much like cake's ACL..so first decide **exactly** what you need, and then look for a way to do it.

In any case, good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am pushing to see if I can solve this Auth/Acl Cake problem, but if not, DarkAuth seems to be a very legit option. It looks like it was written using CakePHP 1.2, but I will work on that... thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

I just recently wrote the probably most simple Auth - I called it "Tiny":
http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/12/18/tinyauth-the-fastest-and-easiest-authorization-for-cake2/

It should be just about what you need.

It does need the roles to be present in the Session Auth, though and that you manage user roles yourself.
So you might have to add this to your login method if you want to use multi role Auth.

Comment: Hey.. this looks good. However, I have finally had success with the Alaxos Plugin_Acl and I am sticking to it to manage my ACLs. However, I appreciate you making this tutorial and I am sure many other CakePHP users will also be grateful. Thanks,

Comment: glad to here that. alexos' plugin has the nice feature that it can be edited from the website (dynamically). such a dynamic approach might be more suitable for some projects. so no hard feelings :)